# slideUp fails on dynamically attached div

Tags: jquery

Here is the code I use to attach the div:

```
$("#sessions").prepend(tempct);
$("#sessions>div:first-child").hide().slideDown(1000).delay(100,function(){
    $("#sessions>div:first-child").click();
    $("#renamemeeting").click();
});
```

here `tempct` is some HTML I wrote, for a simple div structure. The div does get attached and slides down properly.

Next I try to delete the div, like this:

```
console.info("Starting call for element #tr"+chidcl+" and element is "+$("#tr"+chidcl));
                /*$("#tr"+chidcl).slideUp(500,function(){
                    console.log("slideUp was fired");
                });*/
                $("#trOF7VFS").slideUp(500,function(){
                    console.log("slideUp was fired");
                });
                console.warn("Finished call for element #tr"+chidcl+" and element is "+$("#tr"+chidcl));
```

Here the `Starting call...` and `Finished call...` lines are being displayed, but for some weird reason, slideUp doesn't work, neither is the message displayed.

You can see the page here: http://mpsinfoservices.com/projects/sudipta/liveminutes/minutes.html

When the page is loaded, the `div` `trOF7VFS` is automatically attached, now try going to actions menu, and hitting `delete`, and you should see the problem.

Comment: I see this line commented out in minutes.html: `//$("#trOF7VFS").slideUp(500);`.  This won't execute because it's commented out.

Comment: Even if it's uncommented, it won't work

Comment: We can't debug it unless you uncomment it and let us step through it to see why it doesn't work.

Comment: It has already been uncommented

Comment: Still commented out in what I can see.

Comment: That's weird, please try clearing your cache... I rechecked, and it is uncommented. The lines are in minute.js line:182

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5331/discussion-between-aoi-and-jfriend00)

Comment: There's nothing to discuss.  I've now looked in your page 3 times and found it commented out every time.  If you want to direct us to a specific source file and line number where it's not commented out, we can look further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that, for some reason the `slideDown()` effect was being queued(for yet unknown reasons) and actually never ended. The solution was to use `.stop('true')` before `slideUp()`, to clear all previous animation queues.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you've seen this but you have actually commented out the line where it does the slideup. Instead of:

```
/*$("#tr"+chidcl).slideUp(500,function(){
      console.log("slideUp was fired");
  });*/
  $("#trOF7VFS").slideUp(500,function(){
      console.log("slideUp was fired");
  });
```

You actually have:

```
/*$("#tr"+chidcl).slideUp(500,function(){
      console.log("slideUp was fired");
  });
  $("#trOF7VFS").slideUp(500,function(){
      console.log("slideUp was fired");
  });*/
```

Comment: Sorry actually I was testing the code then....but no, that is not the problem, I had the code uncommented while posting this, and I have removed the comment again, but it won't work, at all!